# Using log_in_as helper module in ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, integration-testing

I started learning Rails using Michael Hartl's "Ruby on Rails Tutorial", then I started to customize some classes to suit my own needs.
At this time, I have 2 main classes I can manage with my application:

- "users": admin user can list, create destroy them
- "apps": admin can  list, create destroy them

I recycled most from the tutorial, and managed to make the application working for both of them.

"users" integration testing works fine.
When started to develop the "apps" testing, I found there is something that makes login fail and I'm really stucked on this.
Here is the "users" integration test (it works):

```
require 'test_helper'
class UsersCreateTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  fixtures :all
  def setup
    @admin = users(:admin)
  end

  test "user create with valid information" do
    log_in_as(@admin)
    assert is_logged_in?
    get new_user_path()
    ...
    assert_difference 'User.count', 1 do
      post users_path, user:{ username:  "newuser",
                              email: "user@example.com",
                              password:              "pippo1",
                              password_confirmation: "pippo1",
                              ...
      }
      follow_redirect!
    end
    ...
  end

end
```

Here is the test to create a new "app" (does not work):

```
require 'test_helper'

class AppsCreateTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  fixtures :all

  def setup
    @admin= users(:admin)
    @app= apps(:app1)
  end

  test "create app with valid information" do
    log_in_as(@admin)
    assert is_logged_in?
    get new_app_path()
    ...
    assert_difference( 'App.count', 1) do
      post apps_path, app: { appname:  "newapp",
                              desc: "short descprition here",
                              ...
      }
      follow_redirect!
    end
  end
end
```

Finally, here is the "test_helper.rb" part, which comes straight from the Hartl Tutorial:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  def is_logged_in?
      !session[:user_id].nil?
  end

   # Logs in a test user.
   def log_in_as(user, options = {})
      password= options[:password] || 'pippo1'

    if integration_test?
      post "/login", session: {
        username:   user.username,
        password:   password }
    else
      session[:user_id] = user.id
    end
  end

  private
    # Returns true inside an integration test.
    def integration_test?
      defined?(post_via_redirect)
    end
end
```

The "app" test fails when it tries to do post operation in "log_in_as".
It seems that the "user" test inherits some method while the "app" test doesn't.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Going on with further tests, I found that everything works out well if I comment the @app initialization in setup. I can initialize it inside the test itself.. Can anybody explain this weird behaviour?

Comment: What does the error message(s) in your rails console say when the test fails on ``POST`` request to ``apps_path`` ?